# Porque se chama ao 1 de Maio "dia de saltar à laje"?

Tags: expressões, expressões-idiomáticas, regionalismo

Porque razão é que o dia 1 de Maio é conhecido pelo "dia de saltar à laje"?
Possivelmente, uma tradição só da Madeira.

Comment: Se é um regionalismo, de onde é?

Comment: Esta nunca tinha ouvido. Será expressão lá do sindicato?!

Comment: Possivelmente, um regionalismo da Madeira

Comment: Nunca ouvi por estas bandas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A expressão "saltar à laje" é de origem madeirense, e basicamente, significa praticar adultério.

Este [blog](http://avogi.blogspot.com/2010/05/1-de-maio-dia-de-saltar-laje.html) porque é que o dia 1 de maio era conhecido como "dia de saltar à laje" e as tradições associadas a este dia:

> Antes de conhecer este dia como o "Dia do Trabalhador" sempre o conheci por ser o dia de "saltar a laje". 
>   Logo pela manhã as pessoas enfeitavam as furgonetas (ou meio-carro) com ramos de giesta e colocavam um belo par de cornos. Sim, aquela "cangalha" que os cabritos ostentam na cabeça.
>
> Primeiro de Maio - Dia dos Cornudos.
>   Homens da minha terra, se não saem à rua durante o resto do ano, por causa deles, do peso do adultério e da
>   vergonha, hoje é o vosso dia. Saiam e mostrem que os têm na cabeça. E mais, saiam de braço dado com a autora dos ditos, aquela que os colocou lá bem no alto.
>
> Saltar a laje é adultério. Não há adultério sem cornos. Cornos tem a ver com os cabritos que saltam e pulam as lajes, daí se dizer que os homens com cornos saltam a laje.

Comment: Mas não respondeste à pergunta: porque "saltar a laje"?

Comment: Está no link, mas posso copiar a explicação

Comment: pensei que "saltar a laje" fosse pular do telhado de uma casa para outra.

Comment: Neste dia muitas famílias vão para a serra fazer o piquenique.